# crypto-js DES encryption and padding

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I need Crypto-JS to perform a DES encryption on an 8-byte block (for now). However, I am having problems achieving this in crypto-js without padding.

When I perform:

```
var skl = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt ( CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse ( "0000000000000000" ), CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse ( "0000000000000000"), 
                                 { iv : CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse ( "0000000000000000" ), mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding } );
```

I get no output. CBC mode does not require padding, but I have tried all other block modes (OFB / CFB etc), and still no output.  When I use Pkcs7, it does provide an output but it pads the input block resulting in 16 bytes of ciphermessage.  I guess when you specify padding it always pads even when the block size is compatible?

```
var skl = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt ( CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse ( "0000000000000000" ), CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse ( "0000000000000000"), 
                                 { iv : CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse ( "0000000000000000" ), mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 } );
```

Am I specifying the input data in the correct way (via a hex parse)? It is important that I encrypt raw bytes of fixed sizes & there don't seem to be any examples of this.

What is the correct way to DES encrypt data without padding?